# Linux significantly slower DNS lookup than Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, dns

I've been facing an issue for a while now where on Linux, whether it's Manjaro or Arch, on several computers, has a very long DNS lookup time. Connecting to a new website (i.e. `banana.com`) takes up to 5 seconds (it sits at `resolving host...`), but a refresh is almost instant.

On Windows, it's almost instant regardless.

Doing `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on Linux and `ipconfig /all` on Windows show that BOTH have the same DNS servers:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 2607:f2c0::1
nameserver 2607:f2c0::2
```

```
ipconfig /all
.... (skipping stuff)
DNS Servers . . . . : 2607:f2c0::1
                      2607:f2c0::2
                      192.168.0.1
```

I've tried using OpenDNS/Cloudfare DNS/Google DNS in the router settings as well. I have no VPN running.

How can I fix this slow DNS resolution?

Comment: Are both systems using IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: How can I find out? https://test-ipv6.com/ says both are ipv6, but doing some research it seems that most computers are "both" so I'm not sure if this is relevant

Comment: Could be both, check by doing `ifconfig` on linux and `ipconfig /all` on PC.  Or to shortcut it, try disabling firstly the IPv4 DNS and then the two IPv6 DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and see if it makes a difference.  Also check firewall on linux, make sure UDP is not being blocked and forcing TCP mode or something like that.

Comment: They both have IPv4 and IPv6. There's no firewall on Linux, and I don't think UDP is blocked since I can play games like Minecraft

Comment: By default, Linux doesn't do DNS caching in the OS, so that may slow it down a little, but that shouldn't account for a 5-second delay. Have you been able to determine how much of the 5-second wait is a result of the DNS lookup?

Comment: Based on how long it sits at "resolving host..." in a browser (and how long it takes for other programs like `ping` to get their first feedback), I can't imagine it's anything other than DNS lookup. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many DNS resolvers use the listed DNS servers in order. I notice your two systems have them in different orders. Try putting the IPv6 addresses before the IPv4 one on the Linux machine's `/etc/resolv.conf` and see if that fixes it.

Use a DNS troubleshooting tool like `dig` or `nslookup` to target the 192.168.0.1 server specifically and see if it is up and replying to DNS queries in a timely manner: `dig @192.168.0.1 www.example.com`.

I suspect 192.168.0.1 is the LAN private IP address of your local NAT gateway router, and that its DNS service isn't operating correctly.

Comment: I think this is the answer, but it's important to note that some resolvers send out requests in parallel and take the first answer - its entirely probable the first IP in the list is not responding and in 1 case it waits and tries the second one, while in the other it doesn't need to wait.

Comment: @davidgo Which resolvers do that?

Comment: Windows 10 for a start.    Infact https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn305896(v=ws.11) says that A and AAAA DNS queries are issued in parallel from Windows 8.1 - which would come into play here.   Chrome also does Asynchronous DNS lookups I believe.